# yii basic app, yii-twig classes being set with 0-class when using nav_bar_begin

Tags: yii2, twig, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app, twig-extension

I'm using yii as a basic app with the yii-twig extension, and am creating a navigation menu using nav_bar_begin but the class is being set different to how I expected it to, because of this the navigation menu is grey and not black as it should be.

When I view the source code I see this:

```
<nav id="w0" class="navbar navbar-default" 0-class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container"><div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Application</a>
    </div>
    <div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part that isn't being set correctly for my stylesheet is the very first line, where it has `class="..."` and also `0-class="..."`.

The styles that are in `0-class` should actually of been in `class` instead.

the contents of my main.twig is:

```
{{ use('app/assets/AppAsset') }}
{{ register_app_asset() }}

{{ this.beginPage() }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{app.language}}">
<head>
    <meta charset="{{app.charset}}"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">      
    {{ html.csrfMetaTags() | raw }}
    <title>{{ html.encode(this.title) }}</title>
    {{ this.head() }}
</head>
<body>
{{ this.beginBody() }}

<div class="wrap">
    {{ use('yii/bootstrap') }}
    {{ nav_bar_begin({
        'brandLabel': app.name,
        'brandUrl': app.homeUrl,
        'options': [{
            'class': 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        }],
    }) }}
    {% set menuItems = [] %}
    {% set menuItems = menuItems|merge([
        {'label': 'Home', 'url': ['/site/index']},
        {'label': 'About', 'url': ['/site/about']},
        {'label': 'Contact', 'url': ['/site/contact']},
    ])
    %}
    {% if app.user.isGuest == false %}
        {% set menuItems = menuItems|merge([
            {
                'label' : 'logout (' ~ app.user.identity.username ~ ')',
                'url' : ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' : {'data-method' : 'post'}
            }
        ])
    %}
    {% else %}
        {% set menuItems = menuItems|merge([
            {'label' : 'login', 'url' : ['/site/login']},
        ])
    %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ nav_widget({
        'options': {
            'class': 'navbar-nav navbar-right',
        },
        'items': menuItems
    }) }}
    {{ nav_bar_end() }}

    <div class="container">
        {{ content | raw }}
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; My Company {{ 'now'|date('Y') }}</p>
        <p class="pull-right">{{ Yii.powered() | raw }}</p>
    </div>
</footer>

{{ this.endBody() }}
</body>
</html>
{{ this.endPage() }}
```

This is also my config/web.php file as to how yii and twig is setup.

```
$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'ywLqCkq0cMC-cvfVXiGXFnfu2S41_CbC',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            //'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '/',
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                'about' => 'site/about',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'login' => 'site/login',
            ],
        ],
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
        // setting up twig
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => false, // '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                        YII_DEBUG ? [ 'debug' => true, ] : [],
                    ],
                    'extensions' => YII_DEBUG ? [ '\Twig_Extension_Debug', ] : [],
                    'globals' => [
                        'html' => '\yii\helpers\Html',
                        'url' => '\yii\helpers\Url',
                        'yii' => 'Yii',
                    ],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'layout' => 'main.twig',
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error in widget configuration. Replace

```
    'options': [{
        'class': 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    }],
```

with

```
    'options': {
        'class': 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    },
```

Comment: argh! thank you very much for pointing that out, I've been trying to fix that for a while, and couldn't see what the issue was. looking back at my code I've done in wrong in the first one and then done it correctly as you mentioned for the options further down.

I've since made them both the same as you mentioned and it has resolved the problem, thank you once again!

Comment: @AeroMaxx If you have some `0-*=""` or `0=""` in attributes, it usually means that you have some nested arrays or forget to specify key for value.